# Access Photos stored on WP7 device

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any other way to access the photos stored on a WP7 device other than the PhotoChooserTask?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll` (yes, even in a Silverlight app) you can access the [PicturesCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.pictures.aspx).

```
var ml = new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary();

using (var pics = ml.Pictures)
{
    foreach (var picture in pics)
    {
        // voila! access to the pictures on the phone
    }
}
```